# Passing >2GB data to tf.estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I have `x_train` and `y_train` numpy arrays, each of >2GB. I want to train model using the tf.estimator API, but I am getting the errors:

```
ValueError: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB
```

I am passing the data using:

```
def input_fn(features, labels=None, batch_size=None,
             shuffle=False, repeats=False):
    if labels is not None:
        inputs = (features, labels)
    else:
        inputs = features
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(inputs)
    if shuffle:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle)
    if batch_size:
        dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    if repeats:
        # if False, evaluate after each epoch
        dataset = dataset.repeat(repeats)
    return dataset

train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(
    lambda : input_fn(x_train, y_train,
                      batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=50),
    max_steps=EPOCHS
)

eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(lambda : input_fn(x_dev, y_dev))

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(model, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

The tf.data documentation [mentions this error](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets) and provides solution using traditional TenforFlow API with placeholders. Unfortunately, I don't know how this could be translated into tf.estimator API?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was using

```
tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x_train, y_train, num_epochs=EPOCHS,
                                   batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)
```

instead of `input_fn`. The only problem is that `tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn` raises deprecation warnings, so unfortunately this will stop working as well.